# How can I find an error in the minified version of a script with no errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, minify, flexslider

I just launched [a website](http://dixiecafe.com/) that uses version 2.2 of the FlexSlider library. If you go to that page, you'll see a Javascript error with an unhelpful message:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (near '...Animate(t,true)}}}})(jQuery)...')
```

or if you're in Firefox:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
...{u=""},3e3)}};r.flexAnimate=function(t,n,o,u,a){if(p&&r.pagingCount===1)r.direct...
```

The thing is, if I put FlexSlider in debug mode — that is, use the unminified version of the script — the error doesn't occur.

I've run the minifed version through [javascriptlint.com](http://javascriptlint.com), and it doesn't point out anything too bad.

I've gotten a prettified version of the minified script in Sublime Text; its matching-brace-highlighting fails to match several sets of braces, some of which are siblings of each other, but I can't find any syntax errors by sight in their vicinity.

I've deleted whole sections out of the file until the brace matching worked again to try to narrow down where the error is, but there's not just one section or small identifiable combination of sections I can delete (except for the one that constitutes most of the file) that makes it work.

The thing is, even with this error, *that script works*. It works completely; it just throws an error. But if I turn on my CMS's Javascript aggregation feature as I should, it makes every script *after* this one fail.

I know a one-off answer of where my syntax error is isn't very helpful to the wider community, but are there any techniques or services or programs I can use to help me narrow down what's actually going wrong here?

Comment: try using a jsbeautifier http://jsbeautifier.org/ to be able to read the javascript. Normally these errors come from a conflict with another file etc... so looking into this file and trying to fix it isn't the best way to go.

Comment: @CodeBird, yep, done that already; Safari developer tools provide one, and I mention above that I've gotten a prettified version in Sublime Text.

Comment: Considering the nature of the error that it only occurs when you are in release mode, i.e. minified mode I would suggest that there is a semi colon screwed up or a bracket missing. When I develop javascript I utilise a plugin jslint.net for Visual Studio which follows the "linting" rules of jsLint as specified by Douglas Crockford. Try using that and it may help diagnose the problem better than JavaScriptlint.com can. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Try minifying the unminified file yourself with numerous different minifiers and see if that fixes it.